# Каждый раз перед git commit делать git add?

Tags: git

На занятиях сказали , что

> Важно запомнить следующий момент: команда git commit фиксирует только
> те изменения, которые были добавлены в staging area через git add .
> Поэтому если вы сделаете git add для файла, а затем измените его и
> сделаете git commit ,то ваши последние изменения не зафиксируются, так
> как вы не сделали git add .

То есть, я с утра делаю git add какого-нибудь файла, потом вношу какие-то изменения, снова пишу git add этого файла, а потом git commit? Потом снова пишу git add , потом снова вношу изменения и снова git commit?

**То есть, после каждого commit нужно снова делать add?**

Comment: Изменения -> add -> commit.

Comment: В общем случае да. У `git commit` есть ключ `-a` который добавит в коммит *все* изменения.

Comment: `Потом снова пишу git add , потом снова вношу изменения и снова git commit? ... То есть, после каждого commit нужно снова делать add?` - add делается после изменений, а не после commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коммит попадает только то, что лежит в "индексе" (staging area). То есть вы делаете изменения, потом отправляете эти изменения в индекс, а потом делаете коммит из того, что лежит в индексе.

Обычно это все выглядит так:

1. Вносите изменения в код в своем редакторе
2. Когда все сделано и вы готовы сделать коммит, отправляете измененные файлы в индекс: `git add file_name`. Можно просто писать `git add -A` тогда добавятся все измененные файлы
3. Делаете коммит: `git commit -m "Вечерний коммит"`

То что вам сказали на занятиях, относится ко 2-му пункту. Если вы между пунктами 2 и 3 вдруг сделали какие-то свои дополнительные изменения, то они просто так не попадут в коммит, нужно снова проделать пункты 2 и 3.